# How to keep the null return value from power query?

Tags: powerquery, excel-2016

I have a power query, with some results maybe a null value. How ever, when I import the data into excel, the null value changed to blank. How can I keep the null value?

[image: This is the power query result]
[image: All null turns into blank. I want to see something like in the selected cell.]

Why am I doing so? There are other cells calculating based on this cells. In case there is an error, it means 'this data is not available'. But if it is blank, it will be dealt as 0, which totally has the different meanings.

Comment: FYI, in Excel `NA()` is an error value output, not a null.

Comment: Oh, ok. Is there anything means Null in Excel? If there is not, I would rather use #N/A than blank.

Comment: null = blank in Excel. It's probably a bad idea to introduce errors into your worksheet.  Why don't you want blank cells?

Comment: OK I will add the reason behind in my question.

Comment: Since Excel does not know `null` you could use "replace values" or "transform columns" in power query to replace the nulls with some other value.

Comment: Would be better practice for your dependent cells to handle the "blank" case appropriately, rather than treating blank as 0.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a conditional column with null replaced as "null" ?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is the M code:

```
   #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Tabelle1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Test", type any}}),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each if [Test] = null then "null" else [Test])
in
    #"Added Conditional Colum
```

I hope this helps